# Picard group of the classical Grassmannians

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I think it is well known that the Picard group of the Grassmanniann $G/P$, where $G$ is simple simply connected algebraic group and $P$ is maximal parabolic subgroup, is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$.

I am looking for a reference for that fact.

Comment: That is not true.  For a simply connected, semisimple algebraic group $G$ over a field $k$, the Picard group equals the character group of $P$, i.e., the group of morphisms of algebraic $k$-groups from $P$ to the multiplicative group $\mathbb{G}_{m,k}$.  For some parabolics, e.g., maximal parabolics (not equal to the entire group), the character group is cyclic.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am considering the maximal parabolics. I will modify the question.

Comment: This is usually proved using results about the Bruhat decomposition of $G/P$, but that is just exchanging your original question for a new question: for a maximal parabolic $P$, why is there precisely one Bruhat cell of dimension one?  Assume this for now.  Since the Chow group of one-cycles is generated by the (closures of the) one-dimensional Bruhat cells, the Chow group is cyclic.  Thus, the Neron-Severi group has rank $1$.  Since $G/P$ is simply connected and has vanishing $h^1(\mathcal{O})$, the Picard group is also rank $1$.

Comment: I feel like there is probably a reference in Tits's paper about point-line configurations on projective homogeneous spaces: the closure of the one-dimensional Bruhat cell maps to a line under the projective embedding arising from the linear system of the closure of the (unique) codimension one Bruhat cell.

Comment: My joint paper with Kraft and Vust (on my homepage) has become kind of a standard reference for this type of questions. It is a survey and claims no originality. In a nutshell: if $G$ is semisimple, simply connected and $H$ is a closed subgroup then $\text{Pic}G/H$ equals the character group of $H$.